# Why does a2ensite give me the error "site does not exist"

Tags: apache-2.4

I initially thought I had this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572629/a2ensite-site-does-not-exist-error-even-with-conf-file

But that did not help me.

I cd here:

```
  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

I know the path to a2ensite:

```
  which a2ensite
  /usr/sbin/a2ensite
```

And I tested the configuration files with this:

```
  apachectl configtest
```

I get:

```
  Syntax OK
```

I have this file:

```
  ralph.stagingv2.example.conf
```

which starts with:

```
  ServerName ralph.stagingv2.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/ralph/example/current/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I created the DocumentRoot with:

```
  mkdir -p /home/ralph/example/current/web
```

And I changed permissions to the user we use on AWS:

```
  chown -R ubuntu /home/ralph/
  chgrp -R www-data /home/ralph/
```

but when I do:

```
  a2ensite ralph.stagingv2.example
```

I get:

```
  ERROR: Site ralph.stagingv2.example does not exist!
```

What did I miss?

Comment: What is the path to your `ralph.stagingv2.example.conf` file and what operating system is Apache installed on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a2ensite` is a script that creates a sybolic link in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` pointing to a .conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

In order to work, your .conf file must be in the "sites-available" directory, i.e.

```
 /etc/apache2/sites-available/ralph.stagingv2.example.conf
```

You should NOT actually "place" ANY configuration file in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory.

Comment: That's a nice tip, but not really any issue I want to deal with right now. But hell, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well, what exactly is it that you wanted help with then?

Comment: Note that the file HAS to end with `.conf`, otherwise it is not recognized.

Comment: @Black this is the correct answer!

Comment: I don't have either of the `sites-available` or `sites-enabled` directories. Should I be concerned?

Comment: @Matt yes. You should ask a separate question, though, where you can provide details of your setup and get help either finding the directories, or repairing if possible the deployment. Welcome to Server Fault. Be sure to read up on how to write good questions here, and what is acceptable in the forum, so you have the best chance of getting a good result.